# ZedGraph X-axis scaling programmatically

Tags: zedgraph

I want to change the scale of X-axis. X-axis is of type Date

```
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max =
```

I want the Min to be start of a particular month and Max to be end of the same month

ie

```
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = ***1/3/2011;***
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max=***31/3/2011;***
```

I should be able to give in different month programmatically;
how do I do can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In ZedGraph, dates and time values are handled by the [XDate](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_XDate.htm) object.

So you have to do this way:

```
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = new XDate(new DateTime(2011, 3, 1));
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = new XDate(new DateTime(2011, 3, 31));
```

Because you want the user to enter a month value, here is a solution:

```
var year = 2011;
var month = 10;

myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = new XDate(new DateTime(year, month, 1));
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = new XDate(new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DayInMonth(year , month)));
```

Then it will work with months that counts 30 or 31 days, including february that counts 28 and 29 at leap years.

Comment: Remark for future readers: The DateTime object can also be converted using the `.ToOADate()` method instead of using the `XDate` constructor.